# GPIB low level programming

Tags: gpib

Very ancient device. According to the manual, GPIB commands looks like this:

```
IFC|REN|ATN|DIO7|DIO6|DIO5|DIO4|DIO3|DIO2|DIO1 ||
0  |1  |0  |1   |0   |0   |0   |1   |1   |1
```

For GPIB trying to use this manual https://csi.pl/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/GPIBProgrammingReferenceManual.pdf. On page 13 it says I can do low-level routines.

So how do I program this device? Any help would be appreciated.